# Dynamic switch case with Methods as Map Value - Java

Tags: java, dynamic, switch-statement, maps, java.util.scanner

so my little project has a Scanner and two important methods:

1. That shows the commands i can type in my scanner (runs other methods)
2. A switch-case with the commands

And the following code:

```
static void showCommands(){
    System.out.println("You can enter the following commands: "
            + "\nCommands: Lists your commands. "
            + "\nInventory: Opens up your inventory"
            + "\nEquipment: Let's you equip your items"
            + "\nSpawnItem: Spawns a random item in your inventory"
            + "\nTravel: Travels your character"
            + "\nLocate: Locates your character"
            + "\nClose: Exits the game");
    
    
}

static void useCommands() {
    String input = "";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!input.equals("Close")) {
        input = sc.next();
        switch (input) {
        case "commands":
            showCommands();
            break;
        case "combatlevel":
            CombatLevel.showCombatLevel();
            break;
        case "totatlevel":
            TotalLevel.showTotalLevel();
            break;
        case "inventory":
            Inventory.showInventory();
            break;
        case "equipment":
            Equipment.showEquipment();
            break;
        case "equip":
            break;
        case "spawnitem":
            Item.spawnItem();
            break;
        case "travel":
            Map.travel();
            break;
        case "increaselevel":
            Player.getInstance().combatLevel.increaseCombatLevel();
            break;
        case "locate":
            Map.locate();
            break;
        case "close":
            sc.close();
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is: the architecture is too static, since I always need to update both methods accordingly for each new command and itself it just feels not efficient.

So I wanted to ask if it is possible to maybe use a Map with a key, the String of the user input on my scanner, and the start the method dynamically as the value of the map.

Like:

HashMap<String, Method> test = new HashMap<>();
test.put("test", test());

I tried to do that but it didnt work out, since my test() method had to return another method which did not make sense to me.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix that problem?

Cheers

Comment: You can use a `Map<String, Runnable>` and then do something like `map.put("foo", () -> doFoo())`, then later `map.get("foo").run()`. See http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/lambda-expressions.html

Comment: Can you attach a zip file link of this project? I want to experiment with it and work out a solution.

Comment: Sure give me a minute to upload it

Comment: https://github.com/Notorious1997/rs

Got my inspiration from oldschool runescape, just a little exercise to train my developing skills, cheers

Comment: See the example on the bottom of https://programming.guide/java/function-pointers-in-java.html

Answer (score 1):

Define an interface called `Command` that will represent the action performed. You can then store the relevant Command in a `Map` with the alias as the key. Feel free to look into the [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), it might have some more useful and conventional design.

```java
interface Command {
        
    void execute();
        
}
    
class MyCommand implements Command {

    @Override
    public void execute() {
            
    }
}
```

```java
Map<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<>();
        
commands.put("command", new MyCommand());

commands.put("helloWorld", () -> System.out.println("Hello World"));
        
Command command = commands.get("command");

Command helloWorld = commands.get("helloWorld");
        
command.execute();

helloWorld.execute();
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and I totally get it, but wouldn't I be creating an object for each command that way? Wouldnt that be an issue?

Comment: Java can create millions of objects per second. This is not an issue.

Comment: One last question: That way everything works perfectly fine for one command. But if I had more, I would be executing the same execute(); method for each key in my map, wouldn't I? I'm fairly new to design patterns and intermediate java developing

Comment: @Notorious as Joni has mentioned Object creation isn't a problem. Regarding your question, you're calling the `execute` method on the unique `Command` implementation. Unless multiple keys share the same Command reference you're going to be referencing different instances of the Command class.